# TypeScript typing of non-standard window event in Svelte

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, progressive-web-apps, svelte, svelte-3

I'm using Svelte with TypeScript in vscode and I have the Svelte extension installed in vscode.

In my App.svelte I have

```
<script lang="ts">
  // a bunch of code that isn't relevant. This should just show that 
  // `lang="ts"` is set (above)
</script>

// here comes the crucial part
<svelte:window on:beforeinstallprompt={functionDeclaredInTheScript} />
```

As you can see, in the `<svelte:window>` tag I'm using the `on:beforeinstallprompt` event which is a non-standard event related to progressive web apps that works in some browsers (i.e. Chrome). Unfortunately but understandably, the TypeScript declarations that are active don't have `beforeinstallprompt` on the definition of the `Window` object. (The TypeScript declarations are most likely the ones coming from the Svelte vscode extension.)

The problem I have is that vscode shows an error at `on:beforeinstallprompt` because it thinks that the event does not exist.

The error message is:

```
Type '{ onbeforeinstallprompt: (e: any) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLProps<Window> & SvelteWindowProps'.
Property 'onbeforeinstallprompt' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps<Window> & SvelteWindowProps'.ts(2322)
```

To get rid of the error message I've tried adding a `*.d.ts` file to extend what needs to be extended but I haven't found out what to extend (e.g. an interface) or how that's done.

(Note: I'm aware of the option to use `onMount()` to attach the handler to the `window.beforeinstallprompt` event but I want to know how/if it works with `<svelte:window>`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your `d.ts` file:

```
declare namespace svelte.JSX {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    // You can replace any with something more specific if you like
    onbeforeinstallprompt?: (event: any) => any;
  }
}
```

Then make sure that `d.ts` file is referenced in your `tsconfig.json`. If it reads something like `"include": ["src/**/*"]` and your `d.ts` file is inside `src`, it should work. You may need to reload for the changes to take effect.

Docs: https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/blob/master/docs/preprocessors/typescript.md#im-using-an-attributeevent-on-a-dom-element-and-it-throws-a-type-error